# Streaming without truncating

Tags: json, object, stream, jq

I have json data of the form below. I want to transform it, making the key of each record into a field of that record in a streaming fashion. My problem: I don't know how to do that without truncating the key and losing it. I have inferred the required structure of the stream, see at the bottom.

Question: how do I transform the input data into a stream without losing the key?

Data:

```
{
  "foo" : {
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 2
  },
  "bar" : {
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 2
  }
}
```

A non-streaming transformation uses:

```
jq 'with_entries(.value += {key}) | .[]'
```

yielding:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "key": "foo"
}
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "key": "bar"
}
```

Now, if my data file is very very large, I'd prefer to stream:

```
jq -ncr --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))`
```

The problem: this truncates the keys `"foo"` and `"bar"`. On the other hand, not truncating the stream and just calling `fromstream(inputs)` is pretty meaningless: this makes the whole `--stream` part a no-op and `jq` reads everything into memory.

The structure of the stream is the following, using `. | tostream`:

```
[
  [
    "foo",
    "a"
  ],
  1
]
[
  [
    "foo",
    "b"
  ],
  2
]
[
  [
    "foo",
    "b"
  ]
]
[
  [
    "bar",
    "a"
  ],
  1
]
[
  [
    "bar",
    "b"
  ],
  2
]
[
  [
    "bar",
    "b"
  ]
]
[
  [
    "bar"
  ]
]
```

while with truncation, `. as $dot | (1|truncate_stream($dot | tostream))`, the structure is:

```
[
  [
    "a"
  ],
  1
]
[
  [
    "b"
  ],
  2
]
[
  [
    "b"
  ]
]
[
  [
    "a"
  ],
  1
]
[
  [
    "b"
  ],
  2
]
[
  [
    "b"
  ]
]
```

So it looks like that in order for me to construct a stream the way I need it, I will have to generate the following structure (I have inserted a `[["foo"]]` after the first record is finished):

```
[
  [
    "foo",
    "a"
  ],
  1
]
[
  [
    "foo",
    "b"
  ],
  2
]
[
  [
    "foo",
    "b"
  ]
]
[
  [
    "foo"
  ]
]
[
  [
    "bar",
    "a"
  ],
  1
]
[
  [
    "bar",
    "b"
  ],
  2
]
[
  [
    "bar",
    "b"
  ]
]
[
  [
    "bar"
  ]
]
```

Making this into a string `jq` can consume, I indeed get what I need (see also the snippet here: https://jqplay.org/s/iEkMfm_u92):

```
fromstream([ [ "foo", "a" ], 1 ],[ [ "foo", "b" ], 2 ],[ [ "foo", "b" ] ],[["foo"]],[ [ "bar", "a" ], 1 ],[ [ "bar", "b" ], 2 ],[ [ "bar", "b" ] ],[ [ "bar" ] ])
```

yielding:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  }
}
{
  "bar": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  }
}
```

The final result (see https://jqplay.org/s/-UgbEC4BN8) would be:

```
fromstream([ [ "foo", "a" ], 1 ],[ [ "foo", "b" ], 2 ],[ [ "foo", "b" ] ],[["foo"]],[ [ "bar", "a" ], 1 ],[ [ "bar", "b" ], 2 ],[ [ "bar", "b" ] ],[ [ "bar" ] ]) | with_entries(.value += {key}) | .[]
```

yielding

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "key": "foo"
}
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "key": "bar"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic function, `atomize(s)`, for converting objects to key-value objects is provided in the [jq Cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook).  Using it, the solution to the problem here is simply:

```
atomize(inputs) | to_entries[] | .value + {key}
```

(`{key}` is shorthand for `{key: .key}`.)

For reference, here is the `def`:

#### atomize(s)

```
# Convert an object (presented in streaming form as the stream s) into
# a stream of single-key objects
# Example:
#   atomize(inputs) (used in conjunction with "jq -n --stream")
def atomize(s):
  fromstream(foreach s as $in ( {previous:null, emit: null};
      if ($in | length == 2) and ($in|.[0][0]) != .previous and .previous != null
      then {emit: [[.previous]], previous: ($in|.[0][0])}
      else { previous: ($in|.[0][0]), emit: null}
      end;
      (.emit // empty), $in
      ) ) ;
```